# DateTime syntax error when passing to CGI

Tags: ruby, datetime

I have been trying to solve this syntax error for a while and can't seem to figure it out. Is DateTime not returning an object that can be interpreted by CGI.escape?....Based on what I read in the DateTime docs my code seems like it should work.

Error

```
getTimes.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
endTime=CGI.escape(DateTime.new(2016, 6, 24, 8, 21, 0, ‘+5’))
```

Code:

```
require 'cgi'
require 'date'
#new([year=-4712[, month=1[, mday=1[, hour=0[, minute=0[, second=0[, offset=0[, start=Date::ITALY]]]]]]]]) → datetime
startTime=DateTime.now
#startTime=CGI.escape(DateTime.new(2015, 12, 24, 8, 21, 0, ‘+5’))
endTime=CGI.escape(DateTime.new(2016, 6, 24, 8, 21, 0, ‘+5’))

puts startTime
puts endTime
```

I am using ruby 2.3 if it changes things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the last argument you're passing to `DateTime.new`:

```
endTime=CGI.escape(DateTime.new(2016, 6, 24, 8, 21, 0, ‘+5’))
```

This: `‘+5’` should be this: `'+5'`.

I see this problem pop up a lot when people use a general-purpose text editor (e.g. TextEdit on OS X) which automatically converts quotation marks into "smart quotes." The best solution is to switch to an editor meant for programming (like SublimeText or Atom on OS X). In the meantime make sure you turn off "smart quotes" and other automatic text corrections/substitutions in whatever editor you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using ´? Try straight single quote '